# tcp port 80 redirector in python for windows 7

Tags: python

I want to redirect the port 80 traffic to port 3128 for windows 7 , i want to write it in python.

I am relatively new to this....could you guys help ..by giving me some pointers regarding from where to start.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/483730/ or http://code.activestate.com/recipes/114642/ might be good places to start

Comment: Hi TML,
Thanks for the reply...
i had earlier tried both the examples ,particularly http://code.activestate.com/recipes/114642/ seems quite close....but when i run it ...the the data at port 80 didnt redirect to port 3128 ...
i read somewhere that i need to work with windows filtering platform(wfp) and also that i need to hook the driver with the windows kernel.....
is there anything that pcap can do in this...
I'm really lacking direction ...help me out guys...